# Java 9+ Equivalent to Manifest Defined Splash Screen

Tags: java, manifest.mf

I recently upgraded my application from Java 8 up to Java 12. I used to distribute as a runnable jar file, but am now distributing a runnable image. In the past, I defined a splash screen in the manifest which would display while the app loads (and well before a single line of my code ran). Is there any equivalent functionality I can use now that I have switched from running from a jar file to running from an image?

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation of [java.awt.SplashScreen](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/SplashScreen.html):

> If the Java implementation provides the command-line interface and you run your application by using the command line or a shortcut, use the Java application launcher option to show a splash screen. The Oracle reference implementation allows you to specify the splash screen image location with the `-splash`: option.
>
> For example:
>
> `java -splash:filename.gif Test`

or of the [java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/java.html) command:

> -splash:*imagepath*
>
> Shows the splash screen with the image specified by imagepath. HiDPI scaled images are automatically supported and used if available. The unscaled image file name, such as `image.ext`, should always be passed as the argument to the `-splash` option. The most appropriate scaled image provided is picked up automatically.
>
> For example, to show the splash.gif file from the images directory when starting your application, use the following option:
>
> `-splash:images/splash.gif`

Comment: Unfortunately, the platform specific do not run from the command line in this way. They're constructed using the preview version of jpackage from Java 14, which there is not a lot of documentation on yet.

Do you know if there is a way to bake this in, as the manifest file was? Ultimately that's what I'm really hoping for. (Also, I do appreciate the comment, I might see if this is something I can shoehorn in, depending on how all the images function internally.)

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try this! And even if it doesn’t work, I’m glad to have a definitive answer to whether splash screens are supported in vanilla functionality.